# how to create local variable in a rule recipe in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

how to create local variable in a Makefile recipe in which only it is assignable and also just used there only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe is executed by the shell, usually line by line.  So you'll have to use your shell definition of variables, use escape if your shell uses `$` for variables, and use escapes so that the recipe is logically one line.  For instance on Unix, you can do:

```
target: <dependencies>
        v=42 ; \
        echo $$v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use so-called [*target-specific variables*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-target_002dspecific-variables):

```
foo: bar = 1
foo:
    @echo $(bar)
```

---

Or, if they are not flexible enough for you, consider using `eval`.

`eval` creates/manipulates global variables, so to avoid name collisions, I'd use a prefix for the variables you create with it:

```
foo:
    $(eval _local_bar = 1)
    @echo $(_local_bar)
```